# Does anybody know that why Xcode simulator always has a bad network connection?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode8.1 to develop my iOS app,when I debug it in my device, it runs smoothly.

But when I run it in the Xcode simulator, the network will become very slow and it will take a lot more time than usual to finish the http request, sometimes the request will fail and the log shows the information 'request time out'.

I'm pretty sure that my network connection is OK, does anybody has any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have network Link Conditioner enabled on your laptop? See http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/

Comment: Yes it really helps, does it mean that if we don't install it manually, the simulator just cannot work well?Anyway,thanks!

Comment: No, the simulator works ok without installing the network link conditioner. But if you do have it installed, it is easy to forget it is on and have network "problems" in the ios simulator only.

Comment: That's weird. Before I installed it ,the simulator network is bad. After I installed and turned it on ,the network gets faster. So I it really confused me.

Comment: Could you have another network limiter installed on your laptop and installing the new one just overrides the configuration?

Comment: I have vps installed on my computer to browse foreign websites, but I don't know about its principle very well. It sometimes affects the network,maybe this is the reason.

Comment: The Simulator does not do anything with the network connection; it shares the host OS kernel so uses the host OS networking.